When putting an aligned environment inside a tikz node, how to align the top row with the node's coordinate
I have an amsmath aligned environment inside of a tikz node. I want to align the center of the top row of my aligned environment with the node. The [t] parameter is not working inside the node.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt] 
    node[right] 
    {
    $
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        a^2+b^2&=c^2\\
        E&=mc^2\\
        \Rightarrow\frac{E}{m}&=a^2+b^2
    \end{aligned}
    $
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This sounds like an xy-problem. Can you add a bit more background of what you are trying to do? Maybe it would be easier to create a normal align and use tikzmarks or similar to add whatever you want to the first row?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have a tikzmark arrow from the bottom of an array to the top of an align. These environments are not vertically aligned, so I thought I'd put the second inside a node (especially since it follows some text on its line).

You could anchor your node to the mid west:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (0,0) circle[radius=1pt] 
    node[anchor=mid west] 
    {
    $
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        a^2+b^2&=c^2\\
        E&=mc^2\\
        \Rightarrow\frac{E}{m}&=a^2+b^2
    \end{aligned}
    $
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much, I will accept as soon as I'm able. :-)

@Jasper You're welcome!
